# Move onto next item in array every time function is called JavaScript

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I basically want to change the position of a character every time a function is called.

So this is where I'm calling my function,

```
 timer = game.time.create(false);
 timer.add(2000, this.toggleCurrentCharacter, this);
 timer.start();
```

And my function it calls looks like this,

```
toggleCurrentCharacter:function() {
      var characterArr = [characterA, characterB, characterC];
      var characterPosArr = [LEFT_CENTER, CENTER, RIGHT_CENTER];

      characterA.alignIn(columnLeft, Phaser.CENTER);
      characterB.alignTo(columnLeft, Phaser.RIGHT_CENTER);
      characterC.alignTo(columnLeft, Phaser.LEFT_CENTER);

      console.log("Testing");

      timer.add(2000, this.toggleCurrentCharacter, this);
}
```

the `timer.add` is just making sure my function runs endlessly.

Each time the function runs I want to change the alignment of a sprite I've got, so the `RIGHT_CENTER`, `CENTER`, etc you see.

I figured I'd need an array to iterate over, but I'm unable to understand and figure out how each time I call the function, the `Phaser.RIGHT_CENTER` will iterate over so for example, the next time I call the function `Phaser.RIGHT_CENTER` now looks like `Phaser.CENTER` and so on.

Thanks

Comment: Recursion? Save the current pos in a global variable? Just my first two ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function called rotate:

```
function rotate(array) {
  return array.splice(1).concat(array);
}
```

or any number of other permutations:

```
function rotate(array) {
  return array.concat(array.shift());
}
```

Comment: This only seems to re-order it once though? Even if I keep calling it, it just reorders it one time. Or at least, only re-orders it in one specific way. Each time I call it I've been trying to get it to iterate. So example; [1,2,3] then it's [3,2,1] then it's [2,3,1] and back to [1,2,3] again